# App on iOS Beta won't AutoRotate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios10

I am using an iOS 10 beta, and running an app that supports all orientations.

When I build and run the app using Xcode 7, the iPhone won't rotate.

The hacky solution for now is to then stop running the app, force-quit the app from the iPhone, and then launch it again from the phone. At that point, the rotation works fine.

Has anyone experienced this, any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Xcode 8 beta 2 is available if that makes a difference...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. I want to be using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1 to be able to publish to the app store before iOS10/Xcode8/Swift3 is available.

Comment: If you are using Xcode 7 , meaning you are not adding iOS10 compatibility than probably you can ignore the iOS10 (Beta) problem. You should fix iOS10 bugs with Xcode 8 once you decide to add iOS10 campatibility

Comment: True, though I'm less nervous about this bug being a problem for other users (since there will be so few iOS 10 users until September), but more want to fix this for my own debugging/development. Very frustrating not to be able to test out landscape mode in my app.